# Pandas Group by certain condition

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

my dataframe looks like this:

| Id | name | size | metric | week1 | week2 | ... until week 20 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 54 | foo | 1 | A | 20 | 20 | .... |
| 54 | foo | 1 | B | 0 | 0 | .... |
| 54 | foo | 1 | C | 0.39 | 0.39 | .... |
| 54 | foo | 6 | A | 40 | 40 | .... |
| 54 | foo | 6 | B | 0.50 | 0.50 | .... |
| 54 | foo | 6 | C | 0.39 | 0.39 | .... |

So I have 6 rows for every id, but instead I want only 3 rows. I want to merge row 1 with row 4, row 2 with row 5 and row 3 with row 6.

So my goal is to get something like this:

| Id | name | size | metric | week1 | week2 | ... until week 20 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 54 | foo | 6 | A | 60 | 60 | .... |
| 54 | foo | 6 | B | 0.50 | 0.50 | .... |
| 54 | foo | 6 | C | 0.39 | 0.39 | .... |

-> For row with "metric" A, sum every "week"-column.
-> For row with "metric" B and C, check if values are equal (if not: get the higher value)

I already tried something with:

```py
df.groupby(["id","metric"])[df.columns[4:].sum()
```

But then all rows with "metric" B and C are sum as well.

---

And for the size:
Keep the size where the week values (of metric A) are bigger.
So rows with size 1 have values of 20 and rows with size 6 have values of 40 -> Therefore keep 6 as size.

I know there is a solution with nested loops, but I am pretty sure this can be done with pandas.

Comment: It is great if you can provide the code for creating above df

Comment: @badhushamuhammed you can copy table and use pd.read_clipboard().

Comment: In the expected output week1 week2 for 3rd row is 0.78 right..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
week = ['week{}'.format(i) for i in range(1,23)]
df = pd.read_excel('a.xlsx')
df2 = pd.concat([df.query("metric == 'A'") 
                .groupby(['metric','id','name'],as_index=False)[week].agg('sum'),
           df.query("metric != 'A'")
                .groupby(['metric','id','name'],as_index=False)[week].agg('max')
          ]).reset_index(drop=True)
df3 = pd.concat([df.groupby(['metric','id','name'],as_index=False)['size'].agg('max')]).reset_index(drop=True)
df4 = pd.merge(df2, df3, how='inner', on=['metric'], suffixes=('', '_DROP')).filter(regex='^(?!.*_DROP)')
df = df4.reindex(columns=df.columns)
df
```

1. Create 22-week columns using list comprehension
2. Read file into pandas data frame
3. Group df by metric, id, and name summing all the week columns for metric='A'
4. Group df by metric, id, and name finding the max values of the week columns for metric='B' and 'C'
5. Group df by metric, id, and name finding the max size
6. Merge two dfs without keeping the duplicates
7. Reindex the columns of the final df using the reference of the main df

Output:

```
    id  name    size    metric  week1   week2   
0   54  foo       6      A       60.0    60.0   
1   54  foo       6      B       0.50    0.50    
2   54  foo       6      C       0.39    0.39
```

Comment: Thank you this works. But in my case I had to merge over all 3 columns:    
   
`df4 = pd.merge(df2, df3, how='inner', on=['metric','id','name'], suffixes=('', '_DROP')).filter(regex='^(?!.*_DROP)')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to generate the expected output, assuming that size 6 coming bcz 6 is the max value.

```
data = {"Id": [54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54],"name": ["foo", "foo","foo","foo","foo","foo"],"size":[1,1,1,6,6,6], 
    "metrics":["A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C"], "week1": [20, 0, 0.39, 40, 0.50, 0.39],
    "week2": [20, 0, 0.39, 40, 0.50, 0.39]
   }


grup = df.groupby(["metrics"]).agg({"Id":max, "name":max, "size":max, "week1":sum, "week2":sum})

grup["week1"] = df.groupby(["metrics"]).apply(lambda x: x["week1"].max() if x["metrics"].max() in ["C","B"] else x["week1"].sum())
grup["week2"] = df.groupby(["metrics"]).apply(lambda x: x["week2"].max() if x["metrics"].max() in ["C","B"] else x["week2"].sum()) # Use loop for repeating week column
grup.reset_index()
```

OutPut

| metrics | Id | name | size | week1 | week2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 54 | foo | 6 | 60.00 | 60.00 |
| B | 54 | foo | 6 | 0.50 | 0.50 |
| C | 54 | foo | 6 | 0.39 | 0.39 |

Comment: Thank you, this helps. But for Row 2,3 (Metric B and C) I dont want the sum, I want the bigger value. RIght now, you'll calculate the sum for them as well.

Comment: @danielguo Updated the code. Pleas check

Answer (score 0):

Just another approach:

```
df_pivot = df.pivot_table(index=['Id','name','metric'], 
               values = ['size', 'week1','week2'], 
               aggfunc={'size':'max', 'week1':('sum','max'),'week2':('sum','max')}).reset_index()

n_weeks = 20 #number of weeks

for n in range(1,n_weeks+1):
    week_sum = 'week'+str(n),'sum'
    week_max = 'week'+str(n),'max'
    def week_final(row):
        metric = row['metric']
   
        if metric[0] == 'A':
            return row[week_sum]
        else:
            return row[week_max]

    df_pivot['res'+str(n)] = df_pivot.apply(week_final, axis=1)
    df_pivot = df_pivot.drop(columns=[week_sum, week_max])
```

Output for 2 weeks:

```
    Id  name    metric  size    res1    res2
                        max     
0   54  foo     A       6      60.00    60.00
1   54  foo     B       6      0.50     0.50
2   54  foo     C       6      0.39     0.39
```